# Parsing SpreadsheetML Using Perl

Tags: perl, excel, spreadsheet, spreadsheetml

What's the best way to parse a file in SpreadsheetML format with Perl?  I've tried Spreadsheet::ParseExcel, but it doesn't recognize the format.  Here's the error I get when trying that module:

```
No Excel data found in file
```

It looks like CPAN doesn't have a module that can parse it as far as I can see.

What's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching CPAN for 'spreadsheet excel xml' results in Spreadsheet::ParseExcel, which mentions in the description:

> The module cannot read files in the Excel 2007 Open XML XLSX format. See the Spreadsheet::XLSX module instead.

Worth to try...

Answer (score 2):

The [Spreadsheet::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-XLSX/) or [SimpleXlsx](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SimpleXlsx/) Perl modules can be used to read the XLSX format.

Answer (score 2):

It's XML, use [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig) to process the file or [`XML::XPath`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::XPath) to grab values.